# How to set mindate to current date using mddatedatepicker in angular4?

Tags: php, angular, typescript

I try to set mindate as current date using mddatepicker in angular 4. In .html file I have written

```
<md-input-container class=" col-md-4" style=" padding-left: 15px;">
                  <input onkeydown="return false" [min]="minDate" [mdDatepicker]="picker" [(ngModel)]="InspectionDate"
                    name="InspectionDate" required mdInput placeholder="Inspection Date">
                  <md-datepicker-toggle mdSuffix [for]="picker"></md-datepicker-toggle>
                  <md-datepicker #picker></md-datepicker>
                </md-input-container>
     //In .ts file set minDate as current date
     minDate = new Date(this.today.getTime())
```

When I run the project the calender shows with all dates enabled from current date.But I can't select current date.Once i try to select the current date it shows the validation error.
Screenshot of the form is given below

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nKE1A.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try doing

```
 minDate = new Date()
```

Here is stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-czd9mr

Comment: I have tried minDate=new Date() but it's not working.